# CSS dashboard with buttons collapse when one button is removed

Tags: css, mobile

I am working to wrap my head around css and divs, now I try to build a dashboard look for a mobile site, now the problem is that when I remove one button the whole index page gets distorted, I can only use rows of three buttons here is a example of how things go wrong

http://yellowgreenmedia.info/1/

Can someone please gave look at the code and tell me what it is I keep doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just on a cursory look at the code I see a broken anchor tag....

```
<!-- Header Start -->
<div data-role="header" align="center" data-theme="a"> <img src="images/header.png" width="280" height="195"></a> </div>
<!-- Header End -->
```

Also see an icon image without a wrapping anchor tag, when all other icon image have anchors.

Also seems like you've got far more closing div tags `</div>` than open div tags. I actually count 2 superfluous closing tags which could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix can be to just add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after your last `<a>` tag.

Another option can be to wrap the name in a `<div>` with `style="clear:both;"`

Also, you have 2 extra `</div>` after `<!-- Footer End -->`.